# How to select these IP addresses in notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

I have these IP addresses in a text file:

```
123.456.789.987 |     0x (8B -> 0B)     |N/A
756.789.412.478 |     0x (8B -> 0B)     |N/A
321.745.748.415 |     0x (8B -> 0B)     |N/A
14.48.210.33 |     6x (8B -> 48B)     |N/A
42.117.63.132 |     6x (8B -> 48B)     |N/A
2.6.133.228 |     6x (8B -> 48B)     |N/A
```

I only need to select all IP addresses with `123.456.789.987 |     0x (8B -> 0B)     |N/A`

I need the complete line, to remplace with a blank line, leaving the IPaddresses in this way:

```
14.48.210.33 |     6x (8B -> 48B)     |N/A
42.117.63.132 |     6x (8B -> 48B)     |N/A
2.6.133.228 |     6x (8B -> 48B)     |N/A
```

Comment: I would `grep` them.

Comment: If you insist on using NP++, you can use a regex replacement to add a marker (something like `#`) to the beginning of each line that you want to keep, then use another regex replacement to delete all other lines, and then remove the marker with yet another replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about IP to be kept, but this produces your expected result:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+0x\h+\(8B\h+->\h+0B\).+\R`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  .+        # 1 or more any character
  0x        # literally 0x
  \h+       # 1 or more horizontal spaces
  \(        # opening parenthese
  8B        # literally 8B
  \h+       # 1 or more horizontal spaces
  ->        # literally ->
  \h+       # 1 or more horizontal spaces
  0B        # literally 0B
  \)        # closing parenthese
  .+        # 1 or more any character
  \R        # any kind of linebreak (ie. \r, \n, \r\n)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
14.48.210.33 |     6x (8B -> 48B)     |N/A
42.117.63.132 |     6x (8B -> 48B)     |N/A
2.6.133.228 |     6x (8B -> 48B)     |N/A
```